# Implement document drag to application in macOS using swift

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I am trying to associate a certain filename extension with my macOS application, which I have managed to do by following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html) guide and can drag my file in to my application.

When I drag my file in, I get this exception in the console:

> 2017-11-06 09:56:23.944202+0000 Test App[64192:2356795] [General] readFromData:ofType:error: is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden.
>   2017-11-06 09:56:23.958166+0000 Test App[64192:2356795] [General] (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45f560fb **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6c844c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
>
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45fe7bfd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>
>       3   AppKit                              0x00007fff43a0b860 -[NSDocument readFromData:ofType:error:] + 253
>
>       4   AppKit                              0x00007fff43a0b544 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] + 620
>
>       5   AppKit                              0x00007fff436eb9b9 -[NSDocument _initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 172
>
>       6   AppKit                              0x00007fff436eb89e -[NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 231
>
>       7   AppKit                              0x00007fff437c12dd -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 628
>
>       8   AppKit                              0x00007fff43a42578 __97-[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 91
>
>       9   AppKit                              0x00007fff43a42512 -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:] + 176
>
>       10  AppKit                              0x00007fff437c0493 __80-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 880
>
>       11  AppKit                              0x00007fff43a411b9 __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_4 + 31
>
>       12  AppKit                              0x00007fff43a41542 __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_2.970 + 149
>
>       13  AppKit                              0x00007fff43a4147d __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.969 + 138
>
>       14  AppKit                              0x00007fff43a4133f __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.964 + 254
>
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45eee52c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45ed0f43 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 275
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45ed0d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 3128
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff45ecfe43 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
>       19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff451ef866 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
>       20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff451ef5d6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
>       21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff451ef354 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
>       22  AppKit                              0x00007fff434ec9f7 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
>       23  AppKit                              0x00007fff43c81d98 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
>       24  AppKit                              0x00007fff434e1805 -[NSApplication run] + 764
>       25  AppKit                              0x00007fff434b09a6 NSApplicationMain + 804
>       26  Test App                            0x000000010004cd1d main + 13
>       27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6d433145 start + 1
>       28  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3

I've tried implementing the NSApplicationDelegate openFile functions but none of them are called when I drag the file on to the app:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL]) {

    }

    func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles filenames: [String]) {

    }

    func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openTempFile filename: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

How do I get access to the filename and contents of the "dragged in" file? I am using XCode 9.0.1 and Swift 4.

Edit:

Here is my Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>tal</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Layout File</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.testapp.layout</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>NSDocument</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>v1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.video</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Layout File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.testapp.layout</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>tal</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict/>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So I would have expected `application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String)` to be called when I drag the file on to the app when it's in the Dock...

Comment: The most significant information is *readFromData:ofType:error: is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden.*

Comment: @vadian - I tried to override the read but got a compiler error of "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: You have to override the method in the `NSDocument` subclass. Technically `drag&drop` is sharing data via the pasteboard.

Comment: Can you provide a *complete* example?  I assume this project is using NSDocument and an Info.plist, too.

Comment: @Ssswift - I have added my Info.plist to the post. I thought the `application openFile` would have been called as I "think" I've set the document types up correctly - if I drag the .tal file over my app in the Dock, my app is highlighted and it allows me to 'drop it in'.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of points here to address:

- if you're working in macOS 10.12 or below, you should implement either openFile or openFiles. openURLs is 10.13+ - but you definitely don't need both
- openFile will be called for each of multiple files; if openFiles is present, openFile will not be called, even if you open only a single file
- I have no idea what openTempFile (or openUntitledFile) are about; I haven't been able to get anyone to call either
- openFile(s) get called when you have successfully registered a UTI with the system; double-clicking an appropriate file(s) in the Finder, choosing 'open' or dragging the file onto the dock icon of your app all send an open message that gets handled by the AppDelegate.
  I am not clear what you mean by 'When I drag my file in': if you drag your file onto the app icon in the Finder, openFile(s) should be called; your wording makes me think that your drag destination is part of your application's interface, in which case you need to handle dragging yourself.

Also check - because the linked (iOS) guide does not address this - that you have set your NSDocument class: your example says 'NSDocument', but there is an extreme likelihood that your application uses a custom subclass; so you need to set the 'Class' to that name.